# Correctly reset Scene and keep score in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

So I am making a game in Unity in order to learn how to code, and I have kind of hit a wall again. The game is a "dodge the falling objects game", and the way I am creating the objects is as follows:

```
public class Salt : MonoBehaviour {
    public float delay;
    public GameObject salt;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        InvokeRepeating("Spawn", delay, delay);
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Spawn () {
        Instantiate(salt, new Vector3(Random.Range(-2.5f, 2.5f), 10, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

This part of the code seems to be working fine. The problem occurs when the salt (falling objects) make contact with the player. The game resets like it should, however the salt that was on the screen already is still there and I can't figure out how to delete all of the clones that have already been made. Basically I can't figure out how to clear the objects that have already been created when the player loses.

The way I reset the game after collision:

```
public class TapToStart : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text highScore;
    public Button startButton;
    public ScoreManager sMan;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Init();
    }

    public void Init() {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
        sMan.SetScore(0);
        highScore.text = "High Score: " + Mathf.Round(sMan.GetHighScore()).ToString();
        startButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }



    public void Pressed() {
        startButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
}
```

I thought maybe making a SaltManager object would work, and then just have the Instantiated salt objects be children of it would work so that I could just delete the SaltManager after and all the children would disappear as well, however I can't figure out how to do that and it doesn't seem too efficient anyways. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! -Brandon

Comment: How do you reset the game?

Comment: Just added the edit to the post!

Comment: Why not reset the game by reloading the scene like that you will have the scene exactly as it is at the beginning. Unless if it isn't really an option for you.

Comment: I tried that, but the HighScore resets to 0 when I try it that way. Is there a way to make the HighScore store?

Comment: Of course save your highscore in `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("High Score", 10);` Then you can easily retreive it with `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("High Score")` And like that even if they close your game and come back they will still have the same high score.

Comment: You could re-load the scene, and store your high score in either PlayerPrefs  or in some [singleton](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/unity3d/2137/singletons-in-unity/14518/a-simple-singleton-monobehaviour-in-unity-c-sharp#t=201703210039450621892)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that you reset the game by reloading the scene so like that you get it exactly how it was at the beginning. You can load your scene like that :

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("SceneName");
```

Or with the scene index :

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneIndex);
```

I can see that you're keeping a highscore and its probably why you didn't do it that way. You should save your high score with PlayerPrefs like this :

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("High Score", 10);
```

Then you can easily get it back with :

```
PlayerPrefs.GetInt("High Score");
```

This actually saves your score so that even if they quit the game and come back you can still retrieve it. [More info on PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).

Comment: @CổChíTâm True you can use `PlayerPrefs.Save()`, In case the game crashes so you could use it at some checkpoints but you don't need to put it in `OnApplicationQuit()` because it is called in it by default. And try not to use `PlayerPrefs.Save()` during actual gameplay it's not recommended.